# Compare two list of dictionaries and use similar key to compute

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare, zip

I need to compare two lists of dictionaries:

```
list_1 =
[
    { 
      'key1': {
                'growthScore': 6.7
    },
    { 
      'key2': {
                'growthScore': 9.2
    }
]
list_2 =
[
    { 
      'key1': {
                'growthScore': 7.8
    },
    { 
      'key2': {
                'growthScore': 5.6
    }
]
```

- Iterate through both the lists.
- And compare similar keys and pick the highest score.

OUTPUT:

```
[
    { 
      'key1': {
                'growthScore': 7.8
    },
    { 
      'key2': {
                'growthScore': 9.2
    }
]
```

Comment: so..did you try to do it?

Comment: Yes.  This is what I am doing right now for single list: return max(list , key = lambda x : x.get('growthScore'),default = {})

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  All you've done is to post a problem: no question, no attempted solution, no problem output.

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is the solution:

```
list_1 = [{'key1': {'growthScore': 6.7}},{'key2': {'growthScore': 9.2}}]
list_2 = [{'key1': {'growthScore': 7.8}},{'key2': {'growthScore': 5.6}}]

solution = []
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    for key in list_1[i].keys():
        if list_1[i][key]["growthScore"] > list_2[i][key]["growthScore"]:
            solution.append(list_1[i][key])
        else:
            solution.append(list_2[i][key])

print(solution)
```

PS: please make your question clear and make sure that for every open parenthesis `{` you provide a close one `}`

Comment: Thank you. That worked with slight changes `solution.append(list_1[i])` to get the whole item.

Comment: Glad to hear that, please mark the answer if it helped you